# QML tree view from a model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm quite new to QML and I'm struggling to find any information how to render a tree model in a simple way (although horizontally, rather than vertically):

[image]

Seems like QML only supports list data structures from models. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: There is [TreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html) to display tree data. If you don't like that you always can create your own item using [QQuickItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html) or [Canvas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html)

Comment: TreeView doesn't seem to be capable or rendering models as in the picture. Creating a C++ implementation is what I want to avoid, if possible.

Comment: TreeView is able to display data exactly as you painted.What do you think could be a problem here?

Comment: It can? Like I said, I'm new to this, and all pictures showed only the "typical" tree view. How to make it work? Especially, is it possible to put nodes with the same parent on the same level?

Comment: @folibis so, is it really possible, since no answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. The trick is to use DelegateModel, Repeater and Row/Column layouts, not TreeView.

1. Create a component which will show your current node using DelegateModel.
2. Use a Repeater to create children - let the component dynamically create another instance of itself, assign the current node as the rootIndex of newly constructed DelegateModel, and set it as the model for the Repeater.
3. By properly using layouts, you can position your nodes exactly as in the attached image.

Comment: Hi, I have faced the exact same issue. Could you provide some minimum example how to do it ?

Comment: It's hard to provide a minimum example, but I can show you my resulting code: https://bitbucket.org/krojew/evernus/src/3e92163a5b0c63be1a6046a73ba531a0aa39732e/qml/Industry/Manufacturing/TypeDelegateModel.qml?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default which looks like this: https://evernus.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/manufacturing3.png

Comment: The newly constructed DelegateModel how can keep data consistent？